# Unwrapping a skipped Chars iterator

Tags: string, rust, iterator, substring

Many iterator methods is Rust generate iterators wrapped up in iterators. One such case is the [`skip`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.skip) method, that skips the given number of elements and yields the remaining ones wrapped in the `Skip` struct that implements the `Iterator` trait.

I would like to read a file line by line, and sometimes skip the `n` first characters of a line. I figured that using `Iterator.skip` would work, but now I'm stuck figuring out how I can actually unwrap the yielded `Chars` iterator so I could materialize the remaining `&str` with `chars.as_str()`.

What is the idiomatic way of unwrapping an iterator in rust? The call chain

```rust
let line: &String = ...;
let remaining = line.chars().skip(n).as_str().trim();
```

raises the error

```
error[E0599]: no method named `as_str` found for struct `std::iter::Skip<std::str::Chars<'_>>` in the current scope
   --> src/parser/directive_parsers.rs:367:63
    |
367 |         let option_val = line.chars().skip(option_val_indent).as_str().trim();
    |                                                               ^^^^^^ method not found in `std::iter::Skip<std::str::Chars<'_>>`

error: aborting due to previous error
```

Comment: `Skip` is just an iterator over the items of the underlying iterator but without the first n items. Just use it like an iterator. The nested iterator in your situation sounds unrelated - it's because you are iterating over lines and then over characters.

Comment: `Skip` is an iterator. You need to `.collect()` it.

Comment: It actually sounds like you don't really want to be iterating over chars at all. You probably just want to take a slice of the strings? Doing it via chars  you will need to collect into a a `String`, which seems like unnecessary allocation.

Comment: @PeterHall Yeah, taking slices would be wonderful, but I don't know the byte indices of my characters beforehand. That's why I've been wasteful and dealing mostly with `Chars` iterators.

Comment: Meaning you must handle all valid UTF-8? Depending on your use case, manually walking `.char_indices()` might be a significant improvement. Especially since it saves you an additional allocation. Smells like premature optimization though, make a note in the code and move on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than iterate over `chars`, you can use `char_indices` to find the exact point at which to take a slice from the string, ensuring that you don't index into the middle of a multi-byte character. This will save on an allocation for each line in the iterator:

```
input
    .iter()
    .map(|line| {
        let n = 2; // get n from somewhere?
        let (index, _) = line.char_indices().nth(n).unwrap();// better error handling
        &line[index..]
    })
```

Answer (score 5):

You can retrieve the start byte index of the nth character using the `nth()` method on the `char_indices()` iterator on the string. Once you have this byte index, you can use it to get a subslice of the original string:

```
let line = "This is a line.";
let index = line.char_indices().nth(n).unwrap().0;
let remaining = &line[index..];
```